# In Rails 6 / FactoryBot 6, how do I simulate attr_encrypted attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, ruby-on-rails-6, attr-encrypted

Recently upgraded to Rails 6 and FactoryBot 6.2.0.  I have this model

```
class Store < ApplicationRecord

    …
  attr_encrypted :ein_number,
    key: APP_CONFIG[:app_encryption][::Rails.env][‘secret_key’]
```

I have corresponding factory

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :store do
    name                          { "Test Store” }
    …
    ein_number                 { "00-0000000" }
```

But now when I go and create an instance of this factory, I get the error

```
  Failure/Error: @store = create :store
  
  NoMethodError:
    undefined method `encrypted_ein_number_iv' for #<Store:0x00007feec319fbe0>
```

Not sure what changed in either Rails or FactoryBot but this worked before without my defining such a method.  Seems like sort of a hack anyway.  Is there a more elegant way to define this attribute in a factory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curiously, updating my attr_encryptor on my model to

```
  attr_encrypted :ein_number,
    key: APP_CONFIG[:cfs_encryption][::Rails.env]['secret_key'],
    algorithm: 'aes-256-cbc', mode: :single_iv_and_salt, insecure_mode: true
```

solved the problem (factory created an instance of the object as normal).